# Array as sql request parameter

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I handle my SQL queries like this (which works):

```
const sql = require("mssql/msnodesqlv8");
const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    database: "MyDatabase",
    server: "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
});

async function runSQLQuery(insertReq, query) {
    try {
        await conn.connect();
        var result = await insertReq.query(query);
        await conn.close();
        return result;
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
        return undefined;
    } finally {
        if (conn.connected)
            conn.close();
    }
}
```

and create the querys like this (which also works):

```
exports.getClientByID = async function (ID) {
    var insertReq = conn.request();
    insertReq.input("ID", sql.UniqueIdentifier, ID);
    const request = await runSQLQuery(insertReq, `SELECT TOP (1) * FROM ${ClientTabel} WHERE ID = @ID`);
    return request.recordset[0]
};
```

But now I want to add an Array as Parameter like this (and this doesn't work):

```
exports.getUsersWithProperty = async function (properties) {
    var insertReq = conn.request();
    insertReq.input("properties", sql.NVarChar, properties);
    const request = await runSQLQuery(insertReq, `SELECT * FROM ${ClientTabel} WHERE Property IN @properties`);
    return request.recordset;
};
```

But with this I only get a

> Request Error" Wrong Syntax near "@properties".

I guess the type `sql.NVarChar` is wrong but I don't know what the right type is. Whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, for a start, you need to add brackets around the values.

An IN clause is like this:

```
WHERE somecolumn IN ('value1','value2','value3')
```

you'll also have to make sure that after your @properties string replacement is done, you end up with a statement that looks like the clause above, with the quotes and commas in the right places.

Alternately, if @properties is a string like Value1,Value2,Value3 and so on, you could pass it to a T-SQL table-valued function that returns a table like this:

```
WHERE somecolumn IN dbo.ExtractStringList(@StringList)
```

Comment: I know how it should look like, but I dont how I can make it to look like that if I am using an array as parameter. The only solution I can think of is oldschool foreach and add every string from the array as parameter.

Comment: As I suggested though, try the TVF. I think it'll be your easiest option. You just need a function to split the string. (If you're on SQL 2016 or later, just use STRING_SPLIT as it's now built-in). Then you just pass it all as one comma-delimited string and you won't need to worry about quotes, etc.

Comment: *"You just need a function to split the string."* No they wouldn't. If they are a table-value parameter there would be no need for a splitter. If they passed a delimited string they would, but a table parameter would be better in my opinion.

Comment: `… IN STRING_SPLIT('test,test2,test3', ',')` doesnt want to work. Same error message but with wrong Syntax near STRING_SPLIT.

Comment: Looks like it won't let you just use STRING_SPLIT directly like that. But you can use it like this:
```
DECLARE @ListOfColors varchar(max) = 'Blue,Red,Green';

SELECT *
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE Color IN (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@ListOfColors, ','));
```

Comment: Hi Lamu, agreed that a TVP would be better but pretty sure he's trying to just pass a string, and might not even have support for TVPs

Comment: Never heared of TVP but I want to pass an array. With STRING_SPLIT I now need to `.join` my array first to make it a string so the sql function can use it. Edit. A normal `.join` will add a space after each ','. I need to delete that space too.

Comment: then you just add in a TRIM as well. i.e. SELECT TRIM(value) FROM STRING_SPLIT